# SQL Join Inventory Count Table to Date table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a running inventory table of different products that records the inventory count after every transaction.  Transactions do not happen every day, so the table does not have a running daily count.

I need to have all dates listed for each product so that I can sum and average the counts over a period of time.

inventory

```
DATE        ID  Qty Count
2014-05-13  123 12  12
2014-05-19  123 -1  11
2014-05-28  123 -1  10
2014-05-29  123 -3  7
2014-05-10  124 5   5
2014-05-15  124 -1  4
2014-05-21  124 -1  3
2014-05-23  124 -3  0
```

I have a table that includes dates for a Join, but I am not sure how to make the missing dates join over multiple products.

I need the query as follows.  It needs to to return the counts over the a period selected, but also include dates inbetween.

```
DATE        ID  Qty Count
2013-05-01  123 0   0
2013-05-02  123 0   0
2013-05-03  123 0   0
2013-05-04  123 0   0
2013-05-05  123 0   0
2013-05-06  123 0   0
2013-05-07  123 0   0
2013-05-08  123 0   0
2013-05-09  123 0   0
2013-05-10  123 0   0
2013-05-11  123 0   0
2013-05-12  123 0   0
2014-05-13  123 12  12
2013-05-14  123 0   12
2013-05-15  123 0   12
2013-05-16  123 0   12
2013-05-17  123 0   12
2013-05-18  123 0   12
2014-05-19  123 -1  11
2013-05-20  123 0   11
2013-05-21  123 0   11
2013-05-22  123 0   11
2013-05-23  123 0   11
2013-05-24  123 0   11
2013-05-25  123 0   11
2013-05-26  123 0   11
2013-05-27  123 0   11
2014-05-28  123 -1  10
2014-05-29  123 -3  7
2013-05-30  123 0   7
2013-05-31  123 0   7
2013-05-01  124 0   0
2013-05-02  124 0   0
2013-05-03  124 0   0
2013-05-04  124 0   0
2013-05-05  124 0   0
2013-05-06  124 0   0
2013-05-07  124 0   0
2013-05-08  124 0   0
2013-05-09  124 0   0
2014-05-10  124 5   5
2014-05-11  124 0   5
2014-05-12  124 0   5
2014-05-13  124 0   5
2014-05-14  124 0   5
2014-05-15  124 -1  4
2014-05-16  124 0   4
2014-05-17  124 0   4
2014-05-18  124 0   4
2014-05-19  124 0   4
2014-05-20  124 0   4
2014-05-21  124 -1  3
2014-05-22  124 0   3
2014-05-23  124 -3  0
2014-05-24  124 0   0
2014-05-25  124 0   0
2014-05-26  124 0   0
2014-05-27  124 0   0
2014-05-28  124 0   0
2014-05-29  124 0   0
2014-05-30  124 0   0
2014-05-31  124 0   0
```

Comment: Have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inv join inv` to build up at least 31 rows and construct a table of 31 days. Then join the ids, and finally the original table.

```
select a.d, a.id, a.qty,
  if(a.id=@lastid, @count:=@count+a.qty, @count:=a.count) `count`,
  @lastid:=a.id _lastid
from (
  select a.d, b.id, ifnull(c.qty, 0) qty, ifnull(c.count, 0) `count`
  from (
    select adddate('2014-05-01', @row) d, @row:=@row+1 i
    from inv a
    join inv b
    join (select @row := 0) c
    limit 31) a
  join (
    select distinct id
    from inv) b
  left join inv c on a.d = c.date and b.id = c.id
  order by b.id, a.d) a
join (select @count := 0, @lastid := 0) b;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70d3b/32)

Comment: This looks like it will work.  And I should be able to select over dates and use a subdate to make the range for the limit number.  It needs to order by date and id and then sum the count column to work properly, but overall it seems like that will work.   I'll try and add it to my full table with the edits mentioned above and see how it works.

Comment: @Cascades, oops. Didn't realize `count` shows accumulated values. It's corrected.

Comment: This helped A LOT and essentially works.  Thank you.  My edits were that I ended up using an existing table to create the date rows instead of a cross join.  The cross join had poor performance for how many products I was working with.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps needed:

1. Get all dates between the two given dates.
2. Get the initial stock per ID. This is: get the first date on or after the given start date for that ID, read this record's stock and subtract its transaction quantity.
3. For every date get the previous stock. If there is a record for this date, then add its transaction quantity and compare the result with its stock quantity. Throw an error if values don't match. (This is because you store data redundantly; a record's quantity must equal the quantity of the previous record plus its own transaction quantity. But data can always be inconsistent, so better check it.) Show the new stock and the difference to the previous stock.

All this would typically be achieved with a recursive CTE for the dates, a derived table for all initial stocks at best using a KEEP DENSE_RANK function, and the LAG function to look into the previous record.

- MySQL doesn't support recursive CTEs - or CTEs at all for that matter. You can emulate this with a big enough table and a variable.
- MySQL doesn't support the KEEP DENSE_RANK function. You can work with another derived table instead to find the minimum date per ID first.
- MySQL doesn't support the LAG function. You can work with a variable in MySQL instead.

Having said this, I suggest to use a programming language instead (Java, C#, PHP, whatever). You would just select the raw data with SQL, use a loop and simply do all processiong on a per record base. This is much more convenient (and readable) than building a very complex query that does all that's needed. You can do this in SQL, even MySQL; I just don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL I ended up using to resolve this question used a combination of @Fabricators answer (which really was a correct answer) and my edits.

I ended up using an existing table to create the date rows instead of a cross join. The cross join had poor performance for how many products I was working with.

```
SELECT
POSTDATE,
IF(@PROD_ID = PRODUCT_ID, @NEW := 0, @NEW := 1) AS New_Product,
(@PROD_ID := PRODUCT_ID) AS PRODUCT_ID,
QUANTITY,
IF(@NEW = 1, @INVENTORY := QUANTITY, @INVENTORY := @INVENTORY+QUANTITY) AS 'Count'
FROM (
    (
        SELECT
        POSTDATE,
        PRODUCT_ID,
        QUANTITY
        FROM
        inventory
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT
        dateslist_sub.TransDate AS POSTDATE,
        productlist_sub.PRODUCT_ID,
        0 AS QUANTITY,
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
            TransDate
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                adddate('2013-05-01', @row) AS TransDate,
                @row:=@row+1 i
                FROM
                any_table,
                (SELECT @row := 0) row
            ) datestable
            WHERE
            TransDate <= CURDATE()
        ) dateslist_sub
        cross join (
            SELECT
            PRODUCT_ID
            FROM
            products_table
            ORDER BY
            PRODUCT_ID ASC
        ) productlist_sub
        ORDER BY
        productlist_sub.PRODUCT_ID ASC,
        dateslist_sub.TransDate ASC
    )
    ORDER BY
    PRODUCT_ID ASC,
    POSTDATE ASC
) daily_rows_sub
```

Comment: This may work better as a UNION DISTINCT or RIGHT INNER JOIN so that duplicate POSTDATE's on the final query are reduced.